# Java radio buttons

Tags: java

I'm having trouble with my radio buttons. I can click on all three at the same time. It should be when you click on one the other one turns off?

I'm using a grid layout. So when I try group.add it doesn't work.

Example:

I have the buttons declared like this

```
JRadioButton seven = new JRadioButton("7 years at 5.35%", false);
JRadioButton fifteen = new JRadioButton("15 years at 5.5%", false);
JRadioButton thirty = new JRadioButton("30 years at 5.75%", false);   

 ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();           
 grid.add(seven);
 grid.add(fifteen);
 grid.add(thirty);
```

This is my code:

```
/*Change Request #6
Write the program in Java (with a graphical user interface) 
so that it will allow the user to select which way 
they want to calculate a mortgage: 
by input of the amount of the mortgage, 
the term of the mortgage, 
and the interest rate of the mortgage payment 
or by input of the amount of a mortgage and 
then select from a menu of mortgage loans:

 - 7 year at 5.35%
 - 15 year at 5.5 %
 - 30 year at 5.75%

In either case, display the mortgage payment amount 
and then, list the loan balance and interest paid 
for each payment over the term of the loan. 
Allow the user to loop back and enter a new amount
and make a new selection, or quit. 
Insert comments in the program to document the program.
 */



import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class WK4 extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

  int loanTerms[] = { 7, 15, 30 };
  double annualRates[] = { 5.35, 5.5, 5.75 };

  // Labels
  JLabel AmountLabel = new JLabel(" Loan Amount $ ");
  JLabel PaymentLabel = new JLabel(" Monthly Payment  ");
  JLabel InterestLabel = new JLabel(" Interest Rate %  ");
  JLabel TermLabel = new JLabel(" Years of Loan  ");

  // Text Fields
  JTextField mortgageAmount = new JTextField(6);
  JTextField Payment = new JTextField(6);
  JTextField InterestRate = new JTextField(3);
  JTextField Term = new JTextField(3);

   // Radio Buttons
   ButtonGroup radioGroup = new ButtonGroup();                             
  JRadioButton seven = new JRadioButton("7 years at 5.35%");
  JRadioButton fifteen = new JRadioButton("15 years at 5.5%");
  JRadioButton thirty = new JRadioButton("30 years at 5.75%");      

  // Buttons
  JButton exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
  JButton resetButton = new JButton("Reset");
  JButton calculateButton = new JButton("Calculate ");

  //  Text Area 
  JTextArea LoanPayments = new JTextArea(20, 50);
  JTextArea GraphArea = new JTextArea(20, 50);
  JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(LoanPayments);

  public WK4(){

     super("Mortgage Calculator");



    //Window

     setSize(700, 400);
     setLocation(200, 150);
     setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

     JPanel pane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2));


     Container grid = getContentPane();
     grid.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 10, 0, 12));  //rows, cols, hgap, vgap

     pane.add(grid);
     pane.add(scroll);

     grid.add(AmountLabel);
     grid.add(mortgageAmount);
     grid.add(InterestLabel);
     grid.add(InterestRate);
     grid.add(TermLabel);
     grid.add(Term);
     grid.add(PaymentLabel);
     grid.add(Payment);

     grid.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(15));

     ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup(); 

     grid.add(seven);
     grid.add(fifteen);
     grid.add(thirty);

     grid.add(calculateButton);
     grid.add(resetButton);
     grid.add(exitButton);

     Payment.setEditable(false);
     setContentPane(pane);
     setContentPane(pane);
     setVisible(true);


     // Action Listeners

     mortgageAmount.addActionListener(this);
     InterestRate.addActionListener(this);
     Term.addActionListener(this);
     Payment.addActionListener(this);


     seven.addActionListener(this);
     fifteen.addActionListener(this);
     thirty.addActionListener(this);

     calculateButton.addActionListener(this);
     exitButton.addActionListener(this);
     resetButton.addActionListener(this);



      }

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

     Object command = e.getSource();

     if (command == exitButton) {
        System.exit(0);
     } 
     else if (command == seven) {
        calcLoan(loanTerms[0], annualRates[0]);
     } 
     else if (command == fifteen) {
        calcLoan(loanTerms[1], annualRates[1]);
     } 
     else if (command == thirty) {
        calcLoan(loanTerms[2], annualRates[2]);
     } 
     else if (command == calculateButton) {
        double years = 0;
        double rates = 0;
        try {
           years = Double.parseDouble(Term.getText());
           rates = Double.parseDouble(InterestRate.getText());
        } 
           catch (Exception ex) {
              LoanPayments.setText("Invalid Amount");
              return;

           }

        calcLoan(years, rates);
     } 
     else if (command == resetButton) {

        mortgageAmount.setText("");
        Payment.setText("");
        InterestRate.setText("");
        Term.setText("");
        LoanPayments.setText("");

     }

    }

    private void calcLoan(double years, double rates) {
     Term.setText(String.valueOf(years));
     InterestRate.setText(String.valueOf(rates));
     double amount = 0;
     try {
        amount = Double.parseDouble(mortgageAmount.getText());

     } 
        catch (Exception ex) {
           LoanPayments.setText("Invalid Amount");
           return;
        }
     double interestRate = rates;


     double intRate = (interestRate / 100) / 12;



     int months = (int) years * 12;


     double rate = (intRate / 12);


     double payment = amount * intRate
        / (1 - (Math.pow(1 / (1 + intRate), months)));


     double remainingPrincipal = amount;


     double MonthlyInterest = 0;


     double MonthlyAmt = 0;


     NumberFormat CurrencyFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
     Payment.setText(CurrencyFormatter.format(payment));
     LoanPayments.setText(" Month\tPrincipal\tInterest\tEnding Balance\n");


     int currentMonth = 0;
     while (currentMonth < months) {

        MonthlyInterest = (remainingPrincipal * intRate);


        MonthlyAmt = (payment - MonthlyInterest);


        remainingPrincipal = (remainingPrincipal - MonthlyAmt);


        LoanPayments.append((++currentMonth) + "\t"
           + CurrencyFormatter.format(MonthlyAmt) + "\t"
           + CurrencyFormatter.format(MonthlyInterest) + "\t"
           + CurrencyFormatter.format(remainingPrincipal) + "\n");

        GraphArea.append("" + remainingPrincipal);
      }
    }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     new WK4();
    }

  }
```

Comment: It looks like you and [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727933/plmortgage-calculator-gui-issue-with-a-lot) are doing the same homework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're adding the radio buttons to the grid but you also need to add them to the button group that you defined.

Maybe this:

```
 ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();           
 grid.add(seven);
 grid.add(fifteen);
 grid.add(thirty);
```

Should be this: ??? (Copy/paste bug?)

```
 ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();           
 group.add(seven);
 group.add(fifteen);
 group.add(thirty);
```

Or maybe you need to do both. The radio buttons have to belong to a container as well as a button group to be displayed and to behave properly.

Comment: When I do that they dissapear